# Pivot Table MySQL from mysql database

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I would like to make a pivot table that looks like the figure below from a mysql table:

```
Year                        | 2018  | 2018 |   2018 |  2019   ....
---------------------------------------------------------------
Month                       |  Jan  |  Feb |   Mar  |  Apr   ....
----------------------------------------------------------------
Dolutegravir (DTG) 50mg Tabs| 10000 | 20000|   xx   |  xx    ....
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 xxxxxxxx                   |   xx  |  xx  | xxx    |  xx  .......
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

MySql schema and data can be found here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/678546/2

Your assistance is appreciated in advance

Comment: What query have you tried so far? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql has a working example that should help.

Comment: Also the table you listed above as an example isn't a valid MySQL result - one that has one header defining the columns, and then rows underneath with the results and values for each column. Please edit that to be in a standard format so it's more apparent what type of output you're looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return pivot table output in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql)

Comment: A stored proc:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a partial example [based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql). The basic format is for each column you want in the end, you need to define another `SUM(CASE(x))`. This example currently outputs only 4 months, but you can build it out to include whichever months you need.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/678546/9 for a working example.

```
SELECT  P.`drug`,
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN P.`data_month`='Jan' AND P.`data_year` = 2018
            THEN P.`dispensed_packs`
            ELSE 0 
        END
    ) AS '2018-01',
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN P.`data_month`='Feb' AND P.`data_year` = 2018
            THEN P.`dispensed_packs`
            ELSE 0 
        END
    ) AS '2018-02',
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN P.`data_month`='Mar' AND P.`data_year` = 2018
            THEN P.`dispensed_packs`
            ELSE 0 
        END
    ) AS '2018-03',
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN P.`data_month`='Apr' AND P.`data_year` = 2018
            THEN P.`dispensed_packs`
            ELSE 0 
        END
    ) AS '2019-01'
FROM    tmp_pivot_dtg P
GROUP BY P.`drug`;
```